# Need help writing if statement in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

So I have this script that creates a snap mirror on our dr server based on its location. Below is just a small part of a the script. I need to write an if statement so if location='uk' then to not run the below function otherwise if location='us' then create snap-mirror.

```
function Create-SnapMirror {
    [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false,
                   HelpUri='http://www.microsoft.com/',
                   ConfirmImpact='Medium')]
    [OutputType([Boolean])]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false,
                   Position=0)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$SourcePath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false,
                   Position=1)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$DestinationPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false,
                   Position=2)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$LogName
    )

    $success = $null
    $error.Clear()
}
```

Comment: Where is the `location` coming from?

Comment: its a parameter that would be entered by the user running the script as of this moment only 2 locations exist us or uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the logic is required outside of the function you can achieve this by simply encapsulating the function call within the if statement as follows:

```
if($Location -eq 'us') { Create-SnapMirror -SourcePath $MySourcePath -DestinationPath $MyDestinationPath -LogName $MyLogName }
```

If however you want to check the location within the function you will first need to receive the location either from the input parameters or some other method. Assuming that you have the location in a variable named $Location you can simply add the following within your function before any other action:

```
if($Location -ne 'us') { return }
```

This will exit the function; you can add other actions, for instance logging within the parenthesis.